# incorrect sorting table from A to Z (javascript react)

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs

I use algorythm to sort list of names

```
handleSort(sortColumn, direction){
        const comparer = (a, b) => {
            if(direction === 'ASC'){
                return (a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]) ? 1 : -1
            } else if (direction === 'DESC') {
                return (a[sortColumn] < b[sortColumn]) ? 1 : -1
            }
        }
        const rows = direction == '' ? this.state.rows.slice(0) : this.state.rows.sort(comparer);
        this.setState({rows})
    }
```

From A to Z sort like

```
Sunflower Kinderhub LLP
YMCA CDC @ Bukit Batok
YMCA CDC @ Woodlands
YMCA CDC @ Zhenghua
fff
hkhkhkh
school test
```

From Z to A sort like:

```
school test
hkhkhkh
fff
YMCA CDC @ Zhenghua
YMCA CDC @ Woodlands
YMCA CDC @ Bukit Batok
Sunflower Kinderhub LLP
```

Why it not sorting ?? like :

```
fff
hkhkhkh
school test
Sunflower Kinderhub LLP
YMCA CDC @ Bukit Batok
YMCA CDC @ Woodlands
YMCA CDC @ Zhenghua
```

For simple names, that consist from 1 word, working fine.. how to sort name that created from 3 words?

Answer (score 1):

How about using:

`a[sortColumn].localeCompare(b[sortColumn])` instead `a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]`

Let's see my example:

```js
var arr = ['Sunflower Kinderhub LLP',
'YMCA CDC @ Bukit Batok',
'YMCA CDC @ Woodlands',
'YMCA CDC @ Zhenghua',
'fff',
'hkhkhkh',
'school test'];

console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b)));
```

You can see in MDN for more detail https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: still sorting incorrect, ` fff, school test, YMCA CDC @ Woodlands, YMCA CDC @ Zhenghua YMCA CDC, @ Bukit Batok, Sunflower Kinderhub LLP,hkhkhkh`

Comment: I found reason, it sort first with uppercase letter, then it sort with lowercase